# Refresh Recyclerview from Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a notification which contains a next button and a previous button. Now when I press any of the buttons in the notification the actions are received by the Broadcast receiver.

What my problem is that I am having trouble refreshing my recyclerview when either of the buttons are pressed.

I have been able to do it if I would set my adapter to static in the main class and call it in the broadcast receiver it works like this:

BroadCast Receiver Class:

```
  public void getPlaylistItems(){
    if (list != null){
        list.clear();
    }
    SongsDatabase SongsDB = new SongsDatabase(contexts);
    Cursor data = SongsDB .getSongs();
    if(data.getCount() != 0){
        data.moveToFirst();
        do{
            Songs myList = new  (data.getString(0), data.getString(1), data.getString(2), data.getString(3), data.getString(4));
            list.add(myList);
        } while (data.moveToNext());
    }
    data.close();
    VideoDB.close();

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged <--- This was made static in my Main Activity which contains the recyclerview
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it causes a memory leak in my app.

Now the question is how would I be able to refresh my recyclerview without making any variables static?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are creating an inner class inside your activity/fragment. To avoid making adapter static, you can create this broadcast receiver inside on your `onCreate` function instead.
Other approaches could be using an [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus),Interfaces or [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can without having a static reference to the adapter of your `RecyclerView`. You have the `ContentObserver` for that.

As I can see that, you are fetching the songs and the videos from the local database, you can easily put a content observer along with your database table. In that case, you need to create an `Uri` first which might look something like this.

```
public static final Uri DB_TABLE_SONGS_URI = Uri
            .parse("sqlite://" + Constants.ApplicationPackage + "/" + DB_TABLE_SONGS);

// DB_TABLE_SONGS refers to the database table that you have for storing songs.
```

Now, while updating or inserting a new row in the songs table you need to notify the content observer like this.

```
context.getContentResolver().notifyChange(DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SONGS_URI, null);
```

Now use `LoaderCallbacks` and `LoaderManager` to fetch the data from songs table. Hence, in `onCreateLoader` function you need to register the content observer which will aid to recycle your `RecyclerView` without having any static reference to it.

This is a sample `onCreateLoader` function.

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new SQLiteCursorLoader(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            SongsDatabase SongsDB = new SongsDatabase(contexts);
            cursor = SongsDB.getSongs();
            this.registerContentObserver(cursor, DBConstants.DB_TABLE_SONGS_URI);
            }

            return cursor;
        }
    };
}
```

Do not forget to destroy the loader instance in `onDestroy` function.

```
getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(SONGS_QUERY_LOADER);
```